How to get image from url python?
import requests

# URL of the avatar image
avatar_url = "url.bin"

# Custom headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "*/*",
}

# Send a GET request to the avatar URL with headers
response = requests.get(avatar_url, headers=headers, stream=True)

print(f"Content-Type: {response.headers.get('Content-Type')}")

# Check if the request was successful   
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Save the image to a file
    with open("avatar_VGA23498.bin", "wb") as file:
        file.write(response.content)
    print("Avatar downloaded successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Failed to download avatar. Status code: {response.status_code}")

I want to get image from the URL and save it in local files. But the status_code response is 403. If I click on the URL link. It shows:

<Error>
  <script/>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>96KTSVWPQR3YZHJW</RequestId>
   <HostId>WbjxwXXuo92OUkd+0VP8Pg1rvm6vFWg1s7ciyyxlfr/O4S62Q77yCHJzRb1YnJlIqvlpkP+LduV2wQBUxsDsOQ==    </HostId>
</Error>

How can I get an image from url.bin ?

I don't know what kind of URL you have, but it seems you just don't have access to it. Can you open it in your browser? And if so, are you logged into an account or something which makes it visible for you but not your python script?

You need to construct a request which would be accepted by the server. You may try to imitate requests from your browser (of course if you actually can get the images in the browser). Try to supply all the headers the browser uses.
